# How to programmatically customize "Authentication is disabled, try again in 1 minute" iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to programmatically customize the "Authentication is disabled, try again in 1 minute" alert, that appears when I put the wrong passcode 5 times.

I don’t want to remove the blocked state, I only want to put another button in this alert and disable the existing cancel button.

The objective is to make a better callback, because when this alert is shown, and the users taps *cancel*, the callback is “UserCancel” and this is the same callback you get if the user taps the "Cancel" button before being blocked.

I want to determine which reason resulted in the cancellation of the passcode request.

It is possible to do this? If so, how?

Comment: How is this view currently being created?

Comment: This alert is shown by iOS. You cannot change it.